# Clang compiler ignoring the .a library file

Tags: c, static-linking

This compiling **works** OK:

```
$ clang -target x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0 --sysroot=/opt/cross-freebsd-10/ -l:libconfuse.so main.cpp
```

This one **does not** (undefined references on internal functions):

```
$ clang -target x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0 --sysroot=/opt/cross-freebsd-10/ -l:libconfuse.a main.cpp
/tmp/main-115bc4.o: En la función `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x691): referencia a `cfg_init' sin definir
main.cpp:(.text+0x6ab): referencia a `cfg_parse' sin definir
main.cpp:(.text+0x6da): referencia a `cfg_getstr' sin definir
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**Same error** with these command lines:

```
$ clang -target x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0 --sysroot=/opt/cross-freebsd-10/ -L/opt/cross-freebsd-10/usr/lib/ -l:libconfuse.a main.cpp
$ clang -target x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0 --sysroot=/opt/cross-freebsd-10/ -L/opt/cross-freebsd-10/usr/lib/ -l:libconfuse.a -static main.cpp
```

The files for the [LibConfuse](https://github.com/martinh/libconfuse) C programming library seem to be at the **correct path**:

```
$ ls -la /opt/cross-freebsd-10/usr/lib/libconfuse*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 luis luis 78318 sep 29  2018 /opt/cross-freebsd-10/usr/lib/libconfuse.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 luis luis    19 sep 29  2018 /opt/cross-freebsd-10/usr/lib/libconfuse.so -> libconfuse.so.2.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 luis luis    19 sep 29  2018 /opt/cross-freebsd-10/usr/lib/libconfuse.so.2 -> libconfuse.so.2.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 luis luis 56616 sep 29  2018 /opt/cross-freebsd-10/usr/lib/libconfuse.so.2.0.0
```

So, I would say the compiler **can not see** the `.a` file. Am I right? How could I **solve** it?

I need to solve this because I am trying to compile with **static linking** for the LibConfuse library, as long as I don't need to install that package on destination computers. So, as I have read, the `.a` library file must be used.

**Further Data**:

- Note that I am **cross-compiling** to FreeBSD. I don't know if that matters.
- When running (on a remote FreeBSD computer) the executable generated by the `.so` mode above, the program yields «Shared object "libconfuse.so.2" not found, required by [MyExecutableName]». This is why I am trying to perform static link.
- Tests performed on **Ubuntu** Linux v16.04.

**New data upon requestion**:

Same first line that works OK, but with `-###` parameter to show extra info:

```
1$ clang -### -target x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0 --sysroot=/opt/cross-freebsd-10/ -l:libconfuse.so main.cpp
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
 "/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/clang" "-cc1" "-triple" "x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0" "-emit-obj" "-mrelax-all" "-disable-free" "-disable-llvm-verifier" "-main-file-name" "main.cpp" "-mrelocation-model" "static" "-mthread-model" "posix" "-mdisable-fp-elim" "-masm-verbose" "-mconstructor-aliases" "-munwind-tables" "-target-cpu" "x86-64" "-dwarf-column-info" "-debugger-tuning=gdb" "-resource-dir" "/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/bin/../lib/clang/3.8.0" "-isysroot" "/opt/cross-freebsd-10/" "-internal-isystem" "/opt/cross-freebsd-10//usr/include/c++/v1" "-fdeprecated-macro" "-fdebug-compilation-dir" "/media/Almacen01/Temporal/CPlusPlus/PruebaCSV01" "-ferror-limit" "19" "-fmessage-length" "83" "-fobjc-runtime=gnustep" "-fcxx-exceptions" "-fexceptions" "-fdiagnostics-show-option" "-fcolor-diagnostics" "-o" "/tmp/main-065e9b.o" "-x" "c++" "main.cpp"
 "/usr/bin/ld" "--sysroot=/opt/cross-freebsd-10/" "--eh-frame-hdr" "-dynamic-linker" "/libexec/ld-elf.so.1" "--hash-style=both" "--enable-new-dtags" "-o" "a.out" "/opt/cross-freebsd-10//usr/lib/crt1.o" "/opt/cross-freebsd-10//usr/lib/crti.o" "/opt/cross-freebsd-10//usr/lib/crtbegin.o" "-L/opt/cross-freebsd-10//usr/lib" "-l:libconfuse.so" "/tmp/main-065e9b.o" "-lgcc" "--as-needed" "-lgcc_s" "--no-as-needed" "-lc" "-lgcc" "--as-needed" "-lgcc_s" "--no-as-needed" "/opt/cross-freebsd-10//usr/lib/crtend.o" "/opt/cross-freebsd-10//usr/lib/crtn.o"
```

More data requested by Ahmed:

```
$ clang -### -target x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0 --sysroot=/opt/cross-freebsd-10/ /opt/cross-freebsd-10/usr/lib/libconfuse.a main.o -o LogManager
clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
 "/usr/bin/ld" "--sysroot=/opt/cross-freebsd-10/" "--eh-frame-hdr" "-dynamic-linker" "/libexec/ld-elf.so.1" "--hash-style=both" "--enable-new-dtags" "-o" "LogManager" "/opt/cross-freebsd-10//usr/lib/crt1.o" "/opt/cross-freebsd-10//usr/lib/crti.o" "/opt/cross-freebsd-10//usr/lib/crtbegin.o" "-L/opt/cross-freebsd-10//usr/lib" "/opt/cross-freebsd-10/usr/lib/libconfuse.a" "main.o" "-lgcc" "--as-needed" "-lgcc_s" "--no-as-needed" "-lc" "-lgcc" "--as-needed" "-lgcc_s" "--no-as-needed" "/opt/cross-freebsd-10//usr/lib/crtend.o" "/opt/cross-freebsd-10//usr/lib/crtn.o"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the commandline to:

```
clang -target x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0 --sysroot=/opt/cross-freebsd-10/ -c main.cpp -o main.o 
clang -target x86_64-unknown-freebsd10.0 --sysroot=/opt/cross-freebsd-10/  /opt/cross-freebsd-10/usr/lib/libconfuse.a main.o -o main
```

This will allow you to link the libconfuse.a right into the binary with static symbols. Let me know if you run into trouble

Comment: It yields `/usr/bin/ld: can not find -lgcc_s` twice.

Comment: ah ! I see the issue. let me fix that :P

Comment: Same error, Ahmed. This time on your second line. The first one run without a flaw.

Comment: Hrm... something is up with your cross compile set up. can you give an output of what it says if you put `-###` as the first parameter to `clang` (keep everything the same) do it for the one that WORKs (your top line) as well as my second line?

Comment: Done, Ahmed. I have tested too downloading and extracting again the `.a` file from several sources, with same results.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to link to the library file `libconfuse.a` then you can do that by specifying only the filename (without the -l: part), or you can write `-lconfuse` (the lib and .a parts are then assumed. Writing `-l:libconfuse.a` will not work, I think.

Comment: The `lconfuse` method works, but I guess it is equivalent to the `.o` one. Because adding `-static` yields again the same errors.